# How much area man should cover his body in salah?

Tags: salat, awrah, human-body

If a man has to offer salah,how much minimum area of his body should be covered? answer with reference please

Answer (score 0):

A man's awrah is the navel to the knees. There is mixed opinion on this subject. Some say that this is meant to signify the thighs, penis and behind. Others say it is the entire area that is told. To be safe, I would just cover it, and many people wear clothes that cover more than that.